# Discrete Math-Proof by Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Could someone please check my work and see if this is correct? Thanks.
For all integers $n \geq 1$, prove the following statement using mathematical induction.
$$1+2^1+2^2+...+2^n = 2^{n+1}- 1$$
1) Base Step:

$$n = 0: 2^0=2^{0+1}-1 = 1$$

2) Inductive Hypothesis: Assume that any non-negative integer $n$ that $1+2^1+2^2…2^n=2^{n+1}-1$

3) We must show that $1+2^1+2^2…+2^{n+1} = 2^{n+1}-1$

4) Proof: 
\begin{align*}
1+2^1+2^2…2^n & = 2^{n+1}-1\\
        & = 2^{n+1}-1 + 2^{n+1}\\
        & = 2(2^{n+1})-1\\
        & = 2^{n+1} -1 
\end{align*}

Comment: PLease use Latex

Comment: The base step should be for $n=1$, not for $n=0$.

Comment: See here for a MathJax Tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You are not using the inductive assumption in the proof. You need to show that $1+2^1+2^2+\ldots+2^n+2^{n+1}=2^{n+2}-1$.

Comment: NO; in the induction step you have to prove that $1 + \ldots + 2^{(n+1)}=2^{[(n+1)+1]}-1$.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start with base step $n = 1$.

Then, yes, you assume that for $n = k$, $$1 + 2^1 + 2^2 +\cdots + 2^k = 2^{k+1} - 1\tag{Inductive Hypothesis (IH)}$$

Now we aim to show that $$(IH) \implies 1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^k + 2^{k+1} = 2^{k+2}-1$$

---

$$\begin{align}\color{blue}{(1 + 2^1 + 2^2 +\cdots + 2^k)} + 2^{k+1}& = \color{blue}{(2^{k+1} - 1)} + 2^{k+1} \tag{Inductive step}\\ &= 2(2^{k+1}) - 1 \\ &= 2^{k+1+1} - 1 \\ & = 2^{k+2} - 1
\end{align}$$

And we are done. We have shown that $(IH) \implies 1 + 2^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + 2^k + 2^{k+1} = 2^{k+2}-1$, and hence, together with (the correct) base step verified, we have proven $1 + 2^1 + 2^2 +\cdots + 2^n = 2^{n+1}-1$.

Answer (score 2):

There are several mistakes:

1. Your base step should be from $n=1$.
2. In step 3), right hand side should be $2^{n+2}-1$.
3. You should start from the left hand side of step 3, using your assumption in 2, try to derive the right hand side. Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to prove something more general (note that your specific problem will be solved by taking $r=2$ in the scenario I consider).

**Problem:** Let $a,r\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a\neq 0$ and $r\neq 1$. Then for each integer $n\geq 1$,
$$
a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^n=a\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}.
$$

*Solution.* Fix $r\in\mathbb{R}, r\neq -1$, and let $S(n)$ denote the following statement for $n\geq 1$:
$$
S(n) : 1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^n=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}.
$$
It is sufficient to prove that $S(n)$ holds for each $n\geq 1$; that is, it is sufficient to consider only $a=1$. For $r=0$, we note that $S(n)$ becomes $1=1$. Thus, assume, without loss of generality, that $r\neq 0$.

**Base step ($n=1$:)** For $S(1)$, we have that $1+r=\frac{r^2-1}{r-1}$, and this is true since $r^2-1=(r+1)(r-1)$ and $r\neq 1$.

**Inductive step ($S(k)\to S(k+1)$):** Fix some $k\geq 1$ and suppose that $S(k)$ holds; that is, assume
$$
S(k) : 1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^k=\frac{r^{k+1}-1}{r-1}
$$
is true. In order to complete the inductive step, we must show that
$$
S(k+1) : 1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^k+r^{k+1}=\frac{r^{k+2}-1}{r-1}
$$
follows. Starting with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$, 
\begin{align}
1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^k+r^{k+1}&=\frac{r^{k+1}-1}{r-1}+r^{k+1}\tag{by $S(k)$}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{r^{k+1}-1}{r-1}+\frac{r^{k+1}(r-1)}{r-1}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{r^{k+1}-1+r^{k+1}(r-1)}{r-1}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{r^{k+1}-1+r^{k+2}-r^{k+1}}{r-1}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{r^{k+2}-1}{r-1},
\end{align}
we see that the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$ follows. Thus, $S(k)\to S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 1$.

---

For your problem specifically, consider $S(n)$ where $r=2$.